# Is there a more efficient method to create a Python class object with optional parameters?

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and have a suspicion that I may be carrying over old habits from VB.NET.

I'm trying to create a task scheduler that will read an inputted task, together with the optional parameters of "date" and "priority", which are separated by "//". So an input string can look like any of the below:

```
Do something // 16-6-20 // 1
Do something // 16-6-20
Do something
```

I've created a class called `Task` with four properties, `t`, `date`, `priority` and `checked` (the last one is not important for the purposes of the question.) When the user types in an input string, the string is split and trimmed, and a new class object is created. This is the code:

```
from dateutil import parser
from datetime import datetime

class Task:
    def __init__(self, _t, _date=None, _priority=None, _checked=False):
        self.t = _t
        self.date = _date
        self.priority = _priority
        self.checked = _checked

while True:
    print("Add a new task/event:")
    taskstr = input("> ")
    info = [x.strip() for x in taskstr.split("//")]

    t = ""
    date = None
    priority = None

    if len(info) == 1:
        t = info[0]
    elif len(info) == 2:
        t = info[0]
        date = parser.parse(info[1], dayfirst=True)
    elif len(info) == 3:
        t = info[0]
        date = parser.parse(info[1], dayfirst=True)
        priority = info[2]

    newtask = Task(t, date, priority)
    print(newtask.t, newtask.date, newtask.priority)
```

So my question is simply: is this an efficient method to instantiate a Python object, when I have two optional parameters, or is there a better/more "Pythony" way to do this? Is there a trick that I'm missing? The code works, but I'm not convinced it's the best.

Comment: My only comment would be: I think if you want priority to be an int (for later sorting), so should have `priority = int(info[2])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use *args can skip lot of decisions for the variable length of data.

```
from dateutil import parser
from datetime import datetime

class Task:
    def __init__(self, _t, _date=None, _priority=None, _checked=False):
        self.t = _t
        self.date =  parser.parse(_date, dayfirst=True) if _date else None
        self.priority = _priority
        self.checked = _checked

while True:
    print("Add a new task/event:")
    try:
        taskstr = input("> ")
    except:
        break
    info = [x.strip() for x in taskstr.split("//")]
    newtask = Task(*info)
    print(newtask.t, newtask.date, newtask.priority)
```

Comment: note that input of `foo // 16-6-20 // 1 // mate` will cause `_checked` to be set to `mate`

Comment: It depend on the format of input. The same you can say if there are no // in line, or text for date is not legal date, or wrong input data. Not a commercial software, just to show how it work.

Comment: Thanks, that's a really elegant solution - I wasn't aware you could pass an array of parameters wholesale to a constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `*args` and `**kwargs` but in general there is nothing wrong with your original approach. Please refer to this article that explains the functionality of `*args` and `**kwargs` quite nicely https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python-3

EDIT:
It is quite normal to use `*args` and `*kwargs` in init and it works quite nicely with inheritance. Consider following example:

```
class  Foo:
    def __init__(self,foo=None,bar=None,*args,**kwargs):
        self.foo = foo
        self.bar = bar

class Bar(Foo):
    def __init__(self, required, optional = None, *args, **kwargs):
        self.required = required
        self.optional = optional
        self.barkwarg = kwargs.get('barkwarg')
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bar1 = Bar(0,1,2,3,4)
    bar2 = Bar(0,1,barkwarg=2,foo=3,bar=4)
```

if you print the attributes you can see that the arguments were unpacked and passed to  the base class.

```
    print("bar1.required: ",bar1.required)  # required:  0
    print("bar1.optional: ",bar1.optional)  # optional:  1
    print("bar1.barkwarg: ",bar1.barkwarg)  # barkwarg:  None
    print("bar1.foo: ",bar1.foo)            # foo:  2 
    print("bar1.bar: ",bar1.bar)            # bar:  3

    print("bar2.required: ",bar2.required)  # required:  0
    print("bar2.optional: ",bar2.optional)  # optional:  1
    print("bar2.barkwarg: ",bar2.barkwarg)  # barkwarg:  2 
    print("bar2.foo: ",bar2.foo)            # foo:  2
    print("bar2.bar: ",bar2.bar)            # bar:  3
```

You also do not need `if` when working with `kwargs` but you can use the `dictionary.get(keyname, value)` method as `kwargs` is simply a dictionary.

Comment: So, I'm aware of args and kwargs, but my confusion is this - I thought args and kwargs were for an indefinite number of optional variables. Whereas I will only ever have two - date and priority. Also, can an `__init__` function even take args/kwargs? Also also, even if I used kwargs, I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to get the optional variables to the `__init__` method than using an `if`.

Comment: Thanks for the insightful explanation in your edit!